Speed up Manipulate when including several static 3d plots in Show
I made a dynamic vector visualization
vec3D[x_,y_,z_,m_,d1_,d2_,c_]:=
{c,Arrow[{{x,y,z},x+m*Cos[d1]*Cos[d2], 
                  y+m*Sin[d1]*Cos[d2], z+m*Sin[d2]}}]}

Manipulate[
   Graphics3D[vec3D[0,0,0,m,d1,d2, Blue], Axes->True,
        PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1},{-1,1}}],
         {{m,0.5,"Magnitude"},0,1},{{d1,0,"Angle 1"},-\[Pi],\[Pi]},
           {d2,0,"Angle 2"},-\[Pi]/2,\[Pi]/2}]


I then decided to add axes in different colors intersecting at the origin.
Manipulate[Show[
Graphics3D[vec3D[0,0,0,m,d1,d2, Blue], Axes->True, 
PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1},{-1,1}}],
ParametricPlot3D[Labeled[{t,0,0},"x"],{t,-1,1},
PlotStyle->{Directive[LightBlue,Dashed]}],
ParametricPlot3D[Labeled[{0,t,0},"y"],{t,-1,1},
PlotStyle->{Directive[LightPurple,Dashed]}],
ParametricPlot3D[Labeled[{0,0,t},"z"],{t,-1,1},
PlotStyle->{Directive[LightGray,Dashed]}]],
{{m,0.5,"Magnitude"},0,1},
{{d1,0,"Angle 1"},-\[Pi],\[Pi]},{{d2,0,"Angle 2"},-\[Pi]/2,\[Pi]/2}]

The second one runs much slower than the first one, which I expect has something to do with the ParametricPlot3D objects getting updated even though they are static. How can I tell Manipulate to not update them but still show them in the same graphic?
I found this post but I don't understand the answer.

see if this makes it faster. I am just cheating here by using same method in post you linked to
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics3D[vec3D[0, 0, 0, m, d1, d2, Blue], Axes -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
  p1, p2, p3],
 {{m, 0.5, "Magnitude"}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d1, 0, "Angle 1"}, -π, π, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d2, 0, "Angle 2"}, -π/2, π/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {m, d1, d2},
 Initialization :> (
   p1 = ParametricPlot3D[Labeled[{t, 0, 0}, "x"], {t, -1, 1}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[LightBlue, Dashed]}];
   p2 = ParametricPlot3D[Labeled[{0, t, 0}, "y"], {t, -1, 1}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[LightPurple, Dashed]}];
   p3 = ParametricPlot3D[Labeled[{0, 0, t}, "z"], {t, -1, 1}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Directive[LightGray, Dashed]}]
   )
 ]

The idea is that if you put the static plots in the Initialization section, those get evaluated once. And you should always use TrackedSymbols.
It seems faster for me on V 14


In a Manipulate, if you wrap a specific part of your code in a Dynamic , Mathematica will try to update only this specific part when you move a slider.
It is not always possible, but in your case it works. Try :
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics3D[Dynamic @ vec3D[0, 0, 0, m, d1, d2, Blue], 
   Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[Labeled[{t, 0, 0}, "x"], {t, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[LightBlue, Dashed]}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[Labeled[{0, t, 0}, "y"], {t, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[LightPurple, Dashed]}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[Labeled[{0, 0, t}, "z"], {t, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[LightGray, Dashed]}]], {{m, 0.5, 
   "Magnitude"}, 0, 
  1}, {{d1, 0, "Angle 1"}, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {{d2, 0, 
   "Angle 2"}, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}]  

I quote the tutorial "Advanced Manipulate Functionality" :

In short, Manipulate always wraps Dynamic around the expression given
in its first argument, and normally any changes to variables used in
the first argument will trigger updates of that Dynamic. But when a
variable occurs only inside an explicit Dynamic nested inside the one
implicitly created by Manipulate, an update of the outer Dynamic will
not be triggered, only an update of the inner Dynamic in which it
resides.


$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

vec3D[x_, y_, z_, m_, d1_, d2_, c_] := {c, 
  Arrow[{{x, y, z}, {x + m*Cos[d1]*Cos[d2], y + m*Sin[d1]*Cos[d2], 
     z + m*Sin[d2]}}]}

Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[
  {Thick, vec3D[0, 0, 0, m, d1, d2, Blue]},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  AxesStyle -> {{Blue, Dashed}, {Purple, Dashed}, {Gray, Dashed}},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
  Boxed -> False,
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
 {{m, 0.5, "Magnitude"}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d1, 0, "Angle 1"}, -3.14, 3.14, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{d2, 0, "Angle 2"}, -1.57, 1.57, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {m, d1, d2}]


Include Ticks -> None if you don't want the ticks.
